# How to configure FunkLoad monitor in two servers?

Tags: python, funkload

I have a small problem. How to configure monitor and run?!

Now ,I try use this configuration - but this is not work.

I have two servers: 
1. Imitation server clients (178.216.200.170) 
2. A server application (178.216.200.48)

They should look like files?
- monitor.conf (should by in server 2 - 178.216.200.48)
- TestingClassName.conf (should by in server 1 - 178.216.200.170)

I'm trying to:
monitor.conf

```
[server]
host = 178.216.200.48
port = 8008
interval = .5
interface = eth0
[client]
host = 178.216.200.170
port = 8008
```

and TestingClassName.conf:

```
...
[monitor]
hosts=178.216.200.48
[178.216.200.48]
port=8008
description=My description
```

but it does not work?!

Comment: This is possible? I try, but my idea doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

The Nuxeo responded to me:

You need :

- a monitor.conf file for each server that you want to monitor,
- to bind host and port to something that is reachable from the bencher
- to run the fl-monitor-ctl command on each hosts
- to setup the bencher configuration to point to a list of monitored hosts:

```
    [monitor]
    hosts=178.216.200.48 178 178.216.200.170
    [178.216.200.48]
    port=8008
    description=My first server
    [178.216.200.170]
    port=8008
    description=My second server
```

Then run the bench